# Where can I go to ask about getting a list of certain situations in movies?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Googling doesn't really help. IMDb message boards were my go-to place, but that's over with. I want to ask what movies had bizzare hostage demands in them, but I'm pretty sure that's not allowed here.

Comment: Indeed it's not. But unfortunately, I'm not even sure the question *where else* to ask that on the internet is on-topic on meta here either. *If* you're asking if those questions would be okay *here*, then that would be a reasonable question (to which you already guessed the correct answer).